# How to fix the xml file which missing closing tags

Tags: xml

I have an xml file like below, it is missing closing tags. It is huge file aroung 10000 lines. How do I fix this?

```
<START>
    <FIRST>ABC
    <SECOND>EDF
    <THIRD>GHI
    <FOURTH>JKL
    <FIFTH>MNO
</START>
```

Comment: Can you contact the providers of the xml file? It needs to be coded correctly to be parsed, I'm sure

Comment: You can try using a regular expression.  I put your content into Notepad++ and did a find/replace in regular expression mode.  Find `(<(.+)>[a-zA-Z]+)` and replace with `\1</\2>`

Comment: @mittmemo Awesome.  I wish I can give you 100 points in one shot.

Comment: @Lee Unfortunately I cannot.

Comment: @CoolArchTek Well, if it answered your question, I will write it as an answer and you can accept it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a regular expression. I put your content into Notepad++ and did a find/replace in regular expression mode. Find `(<(.+)>[a-zA-Z]+)` and replace with `\1</\2>`.

Comment: I am extending this question please look at that as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133530/notepad-regular-expression-find-to-include-spaces-and-special-characters

Comment: can you show me how to do this with proper syntax? am unable to do `find (<(.+)>[a-zA-Z]+) xml1.xml ` throws `syntax error near unexpected token `<(.+)'`