# Notepad++ regular expression find to include spaces and special characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this regular expression (below), right now it is finding words in notepad++ (refer post [How to fix the xml file which missing closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119526/how-to-fix-the-xml-file-which-missing-closing-tags))

```
(<(.+)>[a-zA-Z]+)
```

I want to extend this and include white spaces, special characters '-&#/ etc

I want the regular expression to find words with spaces, words with special characters and words ending with numbers etc..

```
SOME - THANK YOU    
ABC #123 CITY ST - 0622805065    
201312161    
BABI'S    
ST - 621    
01-07-14 STORE #739 CITY ST     
FUEL GAS #06 01/06 #000294779    
XYZ 1221 1320 774712 9125 W. KMN
SOME - THANK, YOU
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: What do the examples tell us - they are just some lines of text? What do you want to find and what do you want to exclude? Explain the details of problem in this question, not just by a link to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at a website like http://regexpal.com/ to learn the basics of regular expressions.  It is a very useful skill to have.  Anyways, this regex will look after a starting tag for a string that doesn't contain `<`, `\r`, or `\n`.

In Notepad++, find

```
(<(.+)>[^<\r\n]+)
```

and replace with

```
\1</\2>
```